# Use play-ws within a play project

Tags: playframework

I have a project with both a Play and a simple Akka subprojects.
I would like to share some code doing REST calls to another service between those 2 subprojects. Since one of them is not using Play, I wanted to put this shared code in a 3rd subproject that would depend on play-ws.
Everything compiles fine, but my Play project refuses to start because of this error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: play.api.ApplicationLoader$.createContext(Lplay/api/Environment;Lscala/collection/immutable/Map;Lscala/Option;Lplay/core/WebCommands;Lplay/api/inject/DefaultApplicationLifecycle;)Lplay/api/ApplicationLoader$Context;
```

I guess there is some kind of incompatibility between Play embedded ws library and its standalone version, but I am not sure if there is a way to make it work. Otherwise I will have to duplicate the code (or create a common interface but that would be painful as well). I am using the latest Play! and play-ws (2.6.6 for both).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that play was depending on an older play-ws (play 2.6.6 uses play-ws 2.6.0 apparently). Using the same version everywhere fixed my startup issue.